# How to send an addition sequence after an input without interferring other combination with it?

Tags: mouseevent, autohotkey

I want whenever a `LButton`, `^PgUp` or `^PgDn` is active, it should also send an addition sequence after it. From [Function hotkeys](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Function) and [`A_ThisHotkey`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#ThisHotkey) I can use:

```
LButton:: 
PgUp::
PgDn::
    Send {%A_ThisHotkey%}!wi
```

But then mouse drag is not functional anymore, and it's `^PgUp` that should be re-assigned, not `PgUp`. But none of these works:

```
^PgUp::Send {%A_ThisHotkey%}!wi
PgUp::Send ^{%A_ThisHotkey%}!wi
^PgUp::Send ^{%A_ThisHotkey%}!wi
```

How to do this properly? My workaround is just to divide and rule:

```
^PgUp::Send ^{PgUp}!wi
^PgDn::Send ^{PgDn}!wi
```

But I like to use `A_ThisHotkey` for learning purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
~LButton Up::
~^PgUp Up::
~^PgDn Up::Send !wi
```

Comment: What does the [tilde `~`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Tilde) do? Can I have a variable in the key sequence? For example, if I want `a1b::Send z`, `a2b::Send z` and so on, what should I do?

Comment: When you assign a hotkey it disables the default sending of that particular key, the tilde passes through the key, Hotkey, that was pressed. If you have a Value assigned to a variable above the Assigned hotkeys, you can use that in your send command by enclosing the variable in percent signs. For instance if your variable Z contains a String of characters, like:     Z = This is a string     Than you would simply do this:     Send, %Z%!wi

Comment: I've asked in a separate question: [How to send an addition sequence after a series of input?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51165720/3416774) Also, why should there be an `Up` in each hotkey?