# How to send an addition sequence after a series of input?

Tags: autohotkey

I want every time the series <kbd>Ctrl G</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl G</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> are pressed, it will `Send !wi` afterward. Normal hotkeys work:

```
~^PgUp::
~^PgDn::Send !wi
```

But this doesn't work, although `~^g down enter` isn't an invalid hotkey:

```
~^PgUp::
~^PgDn::
::~^g down enter::
::~^g up enter::Send !wi
```

Also, since I don't know many times <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> will be pressed before <kbd>Enter</kbd>, is there a way to make it skips the middle keys?

Comment: What if some other key is pressed before Enter, e.g. Space or Escape or any key? Or if no keys are pressed? Is there guarantee that Enter will be pressed at all? Why do you need this after all, I ask because such approach asks for complications.

Comment: This is to quickly zoom on OneNote when changing the note. To do that, there must be an `up` or `down ` in between to select the note drop down, and `Enter` must be pressed.

Comment: So a simple solution I can think of requires that there is 100% guarantee that Enter is pressed after you select item. And if not - it gets complicated. Another  simple option is to set 'timeout' for a sequence. then you need to select before some time to trigger additional command. And why not just bind say Ctrl+Enter or some free key for "send Enter and then send zoom" ? It would be much simpler.

Comment: What simple solution are you thinking at? Setting a timeout is good, but in this specific problem it's better to have a prequel sequence? Also using a free key is not reliable, because it can't detect `Ctrl+G` at the start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
~^PgUp::
~^PgDn::Send !wi
~^g::
    Input, key, V L1, {Enter}
    if (ErrorLevel == "EndKey:Enter")
        Send {Enter}!wi
return
```

Comment: is there a way to send a key before `^g` when you only press `^g`? (The rest sequence is still the same)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to set a boolean flag when `^g` is pressed. Then check this flag when `enter` is pressed and fire `!wi` if it is set. This however require that the flag is reset - so if some other key can end the sequence, it must be also reset by those keys (see bottom section of code for examples).

```
await := 0

~^g::
    await := 1              ; set flag 
    tooltip %await%
return

~enter::
    if (await = 1) {
        await := 0          ; reset flag  
        sleep 300           ; safety pause 
        send !wi
        tooltip %await%
    }
return


; note: the 'await' flag must be reset if other
; key can end the sequence.
; here for example escape or mouse click

~esc::
    await := 0
    tooltip  %await%
return

~lbutton::
    await := 0
    tooltip %await%
return
```